# NSManagedObjectContext lock

Tags: multithreading, macos, core-data, locking

I'm writing a multi-threaded application using Core Data.

I'm under the impression that `- [NSManagedObjectContext lock]` does not work as a standard lock. As a proof of concept here is a sample built after the Xcode 3 "Command-line tool" template, "Core Data" flavor:

```objective-c
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  objc_startCollectorThread();

  NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();

  [context lock];
  [context lock];

  NSLog(@"hello world! (context=%@)", context);

  [context unlock];
  [context unlock];

  return 0;
}
```

That should result in a deadlock, instead when running under Mac OS X 10.6.8 or 10.7.4, I've got this log:

```
2012-07-18 16:53:40.206 test[20004:a0b] hello world! (context=<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x20000df40>)
```

Can anybody tell me what is happening?

(if I use instances of NSLock instead of the context, the deadlock happens as expected)

---

here is an excerpt from [Apple Documentation about NSManagedObjectContext lock](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/lock)

### lock

Attempts to acquire a lock on the receiver.

`- (void)lock`

Discussion

This method blocks a thread’s execution until the lock can be acquired. An application protects a critical section of code by requiring a thread to acquire a lock before executing the code. Once the critical section is past, the thread relinquishes the lock by invoking unlock.

Sending this message to a managed object context helps the framework to understand the scope of a transaction in a multi-threaded environment. It is preferable to use the NSManagedObjectContext’s implementation of NSLocking instead using of a separate mutex object.

If you lock (or successfully tryLock) a managed object context, the thread in which the lock call is made must have a retain until it invokes unlock. If you do not properly retain a context in a multi-threaded environment, this will result in deadlock.

Availability
Available in Mac OS X v10.4 and later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that for an unknown reason, subsequent NSManagedObject locks are ignored when happening in a same thread.

Here is another sample code working as expected (no log at execution):

```objective-c
@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (Test)
- (void)testLock:(id)sender
{
  [self lock];

  NSLog(@"hello world! (context=%@)", self);

  [self unlock];
}
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  objc_startCollectorThread();

  NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();

  [context lock];

  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(testLock:) toTarget:context withObject:nil];

  sleep(2);
}
```

Note:

`- (BOOL)[NSManagedObjectContext tryLock]` also return `YES`for any subsequent calls.